# Convert array elements from string to an integer

Tags: java, string, integer, converters

I'm trying to count up the values stored in an array, here is my code:

```
    public void printScores()
{

    String sep = ":";
    File inputfile = new File ("P:/SD/Assignment1/fbScores.txt");

        String [] stringArr;
        String line = "";



        try {
            Scanner filescan = new Scanner(inputfile);
            while(filescan.hasNext())
            {
                line = filescan.nextLine();


                stringArr = line.split(sep);
                if(stringArr.length ==  4)
                {

                    System.out.println(stringArr[0]+"\t [" +stringArr[2]+"]\t|" + stringArr[1]+"\t["+ stringArr[3]+" ]\n");

                }

                else
                {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("String " + line + " does not contain " + sep);
                }



             }
            filescan.close();


        }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("problem " +e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    public void totalGoals()
    {
        int count;
        for (int i = 0; i<stringArr.length; i++)
        {
            //int num[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArr);

        }
    }

}
```

Basically I only want to add the numbers up that are stored in [2] and [3], my totalGoals method at the bottom is where I started, but can't figure out how to change from a string to an integer, any help would be much appreciated!

UPDATE:

public void totalGoals()
        {

```
        int[] num = new int[stringArr.length]; 
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<stringArr.length; i++)
        {
            num[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArr[i]);
            count = count + num[i];
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to parse each string individually - you seem to be trying to do the whole array

```
int[] num = new int[stringArr.length]; //don't forget to declare your num[] array

for (int i = 0; i<stringArr.length; i++)
{
    num[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArr[i]); // stringArr[i] instead of stringArr
}
```

---

Note what this code is actually doing when you break it out of the `for loop` format.

```
int[] num = new int[4];
num[0] = Integer.parseInt(stringArr[0]); //the for loop is starting at 0 and stopping 
num[1] = Integer.parseInt(stringArr[1]); //when it hits 4
num[2] = Integer.parseInt(stringArr[2]);
num[3] = Integer.parseInt(stringArr[3]);
```

In truth, you only need `2` and `3`.. and all you need to do is add them together. You already have a `count` variable you could use instead of `num`

So lets say you only want to loop through 2 and 3... look at the `for loop`

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++)

int i = 0             //your loop is starting at 0
i < stringArr.length; //its ending when i is the array's length (should be 4 judging by your other code)
i++                   // i increases by 1 at the end of each time through
```

So if `0` and `1` are useless, try using `int i = 2`

You have a `count` variable. Maybe it should start at 0.. and rather than setting the `num` variable, you could add the value to your `count` variable.

---

About your method.. By itself it should be working.

I'm also not sure which line is `line 73`

If it is the first line: `int[] num = new int[stringArr.length];` Then either your `stringArr` doesn't exist (for *this* method) or your `stringArr` isn't initialized (again, for this method)

Looking at the code you've shown me, I'm guessing the problem is on that first line.

```
public void printScores() {
    //other code

    String[] stringArr;

    //other code
}

public void totalGoals() {
    int[] num = new int[stringArr.length]; 
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<stringArr.length; i++)
    {
        num[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArr[i]);
        count = count + num[i];
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Done simply like this, you wouldn't even be able to compile. `stringArr` would not exist for `totalGoals`. The two methods are separate and cannot "see" each other's variables.

If you have your code like below - then you are declaring stringArr twice and you have two separate variables named the same thing!

```
{
    String[] stringArr; //This is what totalGoals would be using - it is never assigned

    public void printScores() {
        String[] stringArr; //This one is used and assigned within printScores
                            //but totalGoals cannot see/use it
    }

    public void totalGoals() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, so this has converted all the elements into an integer, however I can't seem to understand how to get a loop going so it will count up the numbers

Comment: You already have the loop going ;) I'll add some details that should help

Comment: Thankyou! New to Java so appreciate the help

Comment: I've tried adjusting the method like you said, however when I call it in the main method "readScores.totalGoals();" it returns:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at readFile.totalGoals(readFile.java:73)
 at main.main(main.java:14)

Comment: Updated - tried to make it so the count would add num[i] as it loops round and print it, however this error is returned: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at readFile.totalGoals(readFile.java:73)

sorry if i'm missing something

Comment: No problem, you are so close, just have to figure out this error. try `System.out.println(stringArr[i]);` at the start of the loop

Comment: Added that to the start of the loop but the same error. Brains starting to hurt haha!

Comment: Have to go now, will post back tomorrow if I still haven't figured it out - appreciate the help mate, thankyou

Comment: are you calling `printScores()` before calling `totalGoals()`? stringArr needs values in it before you can call totalGoals. Hopefully I've helped you understand some - trying not to outright give you the answer.

Comment: Yeah, tried commenting out printScores() so it'd just run the totalGoals method but it didn't work, also tried implementing it into the printScores() method so that it did it all in one method but that didn't seem to work either

Comment: Which line is the "line 73"

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.parseInt(String s)` or `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` to convert your `String`s to `Integer`s or primitive `int`s.

For instance:

```
try {
    String s = "42";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    nfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also use `Scanner.nextInt` if that suits your context better.

Answer (score 0):

Use integer.parseint to parse string to int

```
     if(stringArr.length ==  4)
                        {
        for(int i=0;i<stringArr.length;i++)
{

    int    c = Integer.parseInt(stringArr[2])+ Integer.parseInt(stringArr[3]);


        }
                        }
```

Comment: There are about 15 lines that all have stringArr[2] and [3], I need to put this into a loop to count up [2] and [3] on each line, should I just introduce this into a loop?